# Where do I point to when prompted for app location in azure static website app?

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, svelte, web-frontend, azure-static-web-app

I'm trying to deploy a frontend app written in vs code with Svelte in Azure. I'm using a DevOps repository. When I create a Static Website App in azure the form asks me for the app location. However I'm relatively new to frontend development and I don't know where this is supposed to point to. What is the 'app' in this context?

The help says

> Location of your application code. For example, '/' represents the
> root of your app, while '/app' represents a directory called 'app'.

Under src there is the app.html and app.d.ts. So I tried entering /src. This does not work; "App Directory Location: '/src/' is invalid. Could not detect this directory.". There are also _app folders in .svelte-kit\output\client_app and .svelte-kit\output\server_app. Or it could be that maybe the path is not relative to what I think it is (like one level higher than I think for example). There are so many different interpretations.

So what is the correct folder to point to and how can I make sure that I'm pointing to the right folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note: The terms "app directory", "root directory" and "app root" are the same thing in this context.

The app directory is where you initialized your Svelte app, and this directory should contain a `package.json` etc. This is *not* the `src/` folder. It is `/` in 99% of all cases.

I'll explain what the feature is for, because that should make it clear: This is meant for Git repositories with multiple codebases in it. This might seem a little confusing, so here's a practical example:

I have a simple file hosting app. It consists of a Svelte frontend and a small Cloudflare Worker/Page for sending/receiving the actual files. Instead of creating two Git repositories, I create one, and have them laid out like this:

```
|- .git/
|  |- [internal git files here]
|
|- frontend/
|  |- src/
|  |- package.json
|  |- svelte.config.js
|
|- cdn/
|  |- package.json
|  |- rollup.config.js
|  |- worker.js
```

The frontend deployment is on Vercel, and I set the app/root directory to `/frontend`, and Vercel hosts my frontend:

[image]

And on Cloudflare I set this path to `/cdn` and Cloudflare hosts my backend:

[image]

If you do not have a setup like that and just use one Git repository for your app, you probably want to set this to `/`. Hope that clears it up!